# (anti) join based on partial match

Tags: r

I have two `data.frame`, call them `A` and `B`, each has 3 columns. What is a computationally efficient way to remove rows in `A` where more than 1 column (i.e. 2 or 3 columns) match any columns in `B`?

example:

```
A=data.frame(x1=c('a','a','a','a'),x2=c('b','c','f','x'),x3=c('c','e','g','y'))
B=data.frame(y1=c('a','a'),y2=c('c','b'),y3=c('e','f'))
A
#   x1 x2 x3
# 1  a  b  c
# 2  a  c  e
# 3  a  f  g
# 4  a  x  y
B
#   y1 y2 y3
# 1  a  c  e
# 2  a  b  f
```

I want some function `f(A,B)` such that only row 4 of `A` remains.

- Row 1 is out because `(x1,x3)` matches `(y1,y2)` in row 1 of `B`
- Row 2 is out because there is an identical match in `B`.
- Row 3 is out because `(x1,x2)` matches `(y1,y3)` in row 2 of `B`

An alternative way to think about this is, there can only be at most 1 column that appears in a row in `B` for a row in `A` to survive the join.

One feature that might be useful is that each row in both `A` and `B` is always sorted, so `('a','b','c')` can be a row but not `('a','c','b')`.

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach would be to split the both the dataframes row-wise and remove those rows in `A` which have more than 1 value  in `B`.

```
tmp <- asplit(B, 1)

A[!sapply(asplit(A, 1), function(x) 
    any(sapply(tmp, function(y) sum(x %in% y)) > 1)), ]

#  x1 x2 x3
#4  a  x  y
```